# google script send excel attached file with images

Tags: excel, google-apps-script

I have an google sheet with a script that sends the sheet in an attachment in Excel format. One of my columns is an image, is there a way to add it in the .XLS? The image of the column remains blank.

```
function sendEmail() {

  var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();

  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("name_of_sheet_to_send");

  //var email = Session.getUser().getEmail();    
  var email_ID1 = "email@email1";    
  var subject = "Dates de livraisons erronées";    
  var body = "Hello! Ci-joint la liste des refs dont la date de livraison est antérieure à la date de livraison possible. Happy birthday! (Coeur avec les mans) ";

  var requestData = {"method": "GET", "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  var shID = "xxxxxxxx";
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ ssID + "/export?format=xlsx&id="+ssID+"&gid="+shID;

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);  
  var contents = result.getContent();

  MailApp.sendEmail(email_ID1,subject , body, {attachments:[{fileName:sheetName+".xls", content:contents, mimeType:"application//xls"}]});
```

Comment: By the way, `.xls` isn't the same as.`.xlsx`

Comment: Hi @Rubén indeed it is .xls not CSV, I changed the post thanks a lot

Comment: How do you added the image? Do you used `=IMAGE(url)`?

Comment: @Rubén I tryed different methods, `=IMAGE(URL)` was the first, then I copy pasted te values to have the actual Images. Whn I use the formula, I have a ?NAME in my column when I open the Excel sheet. Quite normal as this formula does not exist in excel. Tht's why I tried to copy paste before running the script but here the cell is blank when I open the excel. Maybe I should try to et the data from the link before making the the attachement?

Comment: @Benoit Gramond For example, how about putting the image blobs retrieved from ``URL`` of ``=IMAGE(URL)`` before the Spreadsheet is converted to xlsx format? But I'm not sure about the result you want. When the image blobs are simply put, I'm worry that it might be not the result you want. So can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for replicating your situation and the result you want? I think that those information will help users think of about your issue.